# How can i know if a contour is open or closed in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

How can i know if a contour taken from 'find contour' function is open or closed in opencv?

**UPDATE**

I tried to apply isContourConvex to this image: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByS6Z5WRz-h2RXdzVGtXUTlPSGc/edit?usp=sharing

i extractes contour with greatest area
and return false.
I change, maybe, contour extraction, dilating?

```
nomeimg = 'Riscalate2/JPEG/e (5).jpg'

img = cv2.imread(nomeimg)

gray = cv2.imread(nomeimg,0)#convert grayscale adn binarize

element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(6,6)) 
graydilate = cv2.erode(gray, element) #imgbnbin

cv2.imshow('image',graydilate)
cv2.waitKey(0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(graydilate,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)   # binarize

imgbnbin = thresh
cv2.imshow('bn',thresh)
cv2.waitKey()

#element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(2,2))
#element = np.ones((11,11),'uint8')


contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgbnbin, cv2.RETR_TREE ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))


# Take only biggest contour basing on area
Areacontours = list()
calcarea = 0.0
unicocnt = 0.0
for i in range (0, len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    #print("area")
    #print(area)
    if (area > 90 ):  #con 90 trova i segni e togli puntini
        if (calcarea<area):
            calcarea = area
            unicocnt = contours[i]


convex = cv2.isContourConvex(unicocnt)
print("convex")
print(convex)
```

Comment: I think cvcontour is based on connected components thus they can't be open.

Comment: so i could never know if in my image i have a circle like 'O' or a "C"? Maybe basing on something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the terms [concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave) (like a C) vs [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex) (like an O) contours.

And guess what, there is a method to check for convexity:

[`cv2.isContourConvex(contour)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.isContourConvex)

Comment: What if contour is shape of C, but thickened version? It won't work,right ? or a thickened Y?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: What wouldn't work? Those are all concave contours. For a thickened letter O, you would get 2 separate contours, both convex.

Comment: yeah, i think you are right. I just confused between concave and convex, sorry.... :)